# Cannot accept sharding commands if not started with --shardsvr

Tags: mongodb

When creating a shard key through mongos, Cannot accept sharding commands if not started with --shardsvr is displayed, but the shard set has been added.

I checked my configuration and found that the shards have been added.I configured three shard clusters using docker，and the configuration information shows three shards

```
shardingVersion
{
  _id: 1,
  minCompatibleVersion: 5,
  currentVersion: 6,
  clusterId: ObjectId("640aa3247a56905aabdee85b")
}
---
shards
[
  {
    _id: 'shard1',
    host: 'shard1/shard1-server1:27017,shard1-server2:27017',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp({ t: 1678440200, i: 4 })
  },
  {
    _id: 'shard2',
    host: 'shard2/shard2-server1:27017,shard2-server2:27017',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp({ t: 1678440295, i: 5 })
  },
  {
    _id: 'shard3',
    host: 'shard3/shard3-server1:27017,shard3-server2:27017',
    state: 1,
    topologyTime: Timestamp({ t: 1678440595, i: 4 })
  }
]
---
active mongoses
[ { '6.0.4': 1 } ]
---
autosplit
{ 'Currently enabled': 'no' }
---
balancer
{
  'Currently enabled': 'no',
  'Currently running': 'no',
  'Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts': 0,
  'Migration Results for the last 24 hours': 'No recent migrations'
}
---
databases
[
  {
    database: { _id: 'config', primary: 'config', partitioned: true },
    collections: {
      'config.system.sessions': {
        shardKey: { _id: 1 },
        unique: false,
        balancing: true,
        chunkMetadata: [ { shard: 'shard1', nChunks: 1024 } ],
        chunks: [
          'too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print'
        ],
        tags: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    database: {
      _id: 'pdmp',
      primary: 'shard2',
      partitioned: false,
      version: {
        uuid: new UUID("988c9ba7-efe9-45b1-97af-c786c9c407e7"),
        timestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1678850827, i: 2 }),
        lastMod: 1
      }
    },
    collections: {}
  },
  {
    database: {
      _id: 'pro',
      primary: 'shard3',
      partitioned: false,
      version: {
        uuid: new UUID("0088a7d2-6628-4cdf-8cf4-a522dca6befc"),
        timestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1678866415, i: 1 }),
        lastMod: 1
      }
    },
    collections: {}
  },
  {
    database: {
      _id: 'test',
      primary: 'shard3',
      partitioned: false,
      version: {
        uuid: new UUID("8b3bc5d8-58d0-420e-9b59-07d9100f0eee"),
        timestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1678850901, i: 1 }),
        lastMod: 1
      }
    },
    collections: {}
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the command you try to run?

Comment: I connect to mongos, switch to the admin database, and increase the shard key. sh.shardCollection("admin.pdmp",{test:1})

Comment: Datebase `admin` is an internal database, you should not use it for any application data. I guess you mix terms "database", "collection" and "namespace". A `namespace` is `<database>.<collection>`, for the others see [Databases and Collections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/databases-and-collections/). I assume the correct command would be `sh.shardCollection("pro.pdmp",{test:1})`

Comment: The database pro is created in shard3 after my deployment is complete. Running the above command will report an error "Cannot accept sharding commands if sharding state has not been initialized with a shardIdentity document"

Comment: It is rather difficult if you don't use correct terms. You cannot "increase" a shard key. A database is not created in a shard, a database is created across the entire deployment, perhaps you mix it with "primary shard". Still not clear what you did. Please provide exact commands you exectued and exact error messages. What is the output of `db.adminCommand("getShardMap").map`? Please edit your question for such information instead of adding comments. And please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Thank you very much, I re-deployed the shard cluster, and now it works, I think my steps and configuration information during deployment are wrong